# Generating random integers with different upper bounds using Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, random

When using `numpy.random`, we are able to generate multiple random integer numbers with different upper limits . I was wondering if the same is possible when using `tf.random.uniform`. For example, If I want to generate two integers where they are bounded above by 5 and 4, what I can do:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.randint([5,4])

array([0, 2])
```

However, the same is not working when I use `tensorflow`. This is because `minval` and `maxval` must be a single number. I don't want to use a for loop, because I know that it will slow down the training process. What are some alternatives here if any exist?

```
tf.random.uniform([1,2],minval=[1,1], maxval=[5,4], dtype=tf.int32)
```

**EDIT:**

Time comparison:

```
import time 

start = time.time()
lim =np.random.randint(1, 10000, size=500000)
x = np.random.randint(lim)
print(x.shape)
print("time: ", time.time()-start)
(500000,)
time:  0.03663229942321777
```

Generating 500000 numbers took 0.03 seconds with `random.randint`. If I use `tf.experimental.numpy.random.randint`, generating only 15 numbers took the same amount of time.

```
l = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randint(1, 2, size=15), tf.int32)
h = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randint(2, 10000, size=15), tf.int32)

bounds = tf.stack([l, h], axis=1)
start = time.time()
z = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda x: tf.experimental.numpy.random.randint(low=x[0], high=x[1]), elems=bounds)
print(tf.shape(z))
print("time: ", time.time()-start)
tf.Tensor([15], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
time:  0.03790450096130371
```

Comment: What exactly do you need the random tensors for ?

Comment: I will be using random tensors to predict output at every epoch. For instance, suppose I have an image. I will be randomly increasing one of the pixels and use the current network weights to make a prediction inside the loss function

Comment: Ok, but how do you determine how many random tensors? Depending on the batch size?

Comment: That is correct. It will be determined by i) the number of batches, and ii) a user-defined value.

Comment: And each random tensor should be created with different upper bounds?

Comment: Yes, the upper bounds will be based upon the images that I use as a training point. Hence, the upper bounds will vary. Note that I could generate everything in advance with NumPy and turn it into a tensor object, but it takes too much space. Hence, I would like to create things on the fly.

Comment: Also, since I am using tf.function by hoping that it will speed up my training, I am not able to call numpy functions.

Answer (score 0):

```py
minval = tf.constant([1, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
maxval = tf.constant([5, 4], dtype=tf.float32)

for _ in range(10):
    random_int = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform(shape=tf.shape(minval)) * (maxval - minval) + minval, dtype=tf.int32)
    print(random_int)

# tf.Tensor([3 1], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([2 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([4 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([1 1], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([2 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([4 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([1 1], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([1 1], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([4 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([3 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Yeah...but OP does not want to use a loop..

Comment: Thanks, but using a for loop is going to be super slow when I get into the training step. I will be using this operation during loss calculation in a neural network.

Comment: Loop above is just for illustration of randomness. In TF graph use `tf.random.uniform` will provide efferent value each graph execution (on each train step for example). P.S. for bechmarking  use tf.function, warming up and with huge tensor shapes. Testing TensorFlow in eager mode is meaningless.

Comment: I will set a deterministic seed to make sure that I obtain the same values at every epoch. Also, I am using tf.function on my side.

Comment: Technically, eager mode is activated by default by ````tensorflow 2.6.0```` . Even if I disable it, it does not give a huge boost.

Comment: I you need the same random values each epoch there should be no needs to sample them with Tensorflow. Tensorflow graph execution is usually used for single training steps.

Comment: Yes, but the goal is not to generate anything before the training starts to save from the space. Then, once the training starts, I need these random tensors to have sophisticated loss calculations. Clearly, I must obtain the same random numbers to make sure that at every epoch the calculations are consistent.